# Prism IDialogService Show Non-Modal Dialog acts as Modal

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

In WPF Prism 7.2 I have followed the [`IDialogService` instructions shown here](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/dialog-service.html).

I have a `PlotsDialogPanel` `UserControl` with a single `ContentControl` as shown here:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PlotModule.Dialogs.Views.PlotsDialogPanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PlotModule.Dialogs.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="prism:Dialog.WindowStartupLocation" Value="CenterScreen" />
            <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="CanResizeWithGrip"/>
            <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="PlotsDialogDisplayRegion" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In my `PlotModule` `RegisterTypes` method I register the dialog:

```
public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
   containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<PlotsDialogPanel, PlotsDialogPanelViewModel>();
}
```

But when the dialog is shown in an event handler it acts as modal, it is always topmost on the parent.

```
private void MainMenuEventHandler(string inParameter)
{
   _DialogService.Show("PlotsDialogPanel", new DialogParameters(), r => {});
}
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong here, any ideas on why the dialog is behaving as a modal? Everything else works as expected and the dialog shows and closes with the `IDialogAware::OnDialogOpened` and `OnDialogClosed` functioning as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not actually modal, just the top most window. A modal dialog is shown using the `ShowDialog` method an will not only be the top most window, but also disable any user interaction with its owner window until dismissed.

The reason for a dialog being on top of another window is that it has an owner window assigned to its `Owner` property. By default, Prism will always assign the first *active* window in the application as the owner of the dialog, unless you have set an owner that is **not null** explictly on the dialog host window.

See the implementation for [`DialogService`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/a2231bee4a5d7cb41eefc384a871831583eb63f9/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Services/Dialogs/DialogService.cs#L117) on GitHub for reference. This line sets the `Owner` of a dialog.

```
if (window.Owner == null)
   window.Owner = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
```

Since this is the way that the `DialogService` is implemented, you have to create your own dialog service and change the behavior. You could for example provide an overload to not set an owner. Implement the original `IDialogService` interface to provide compatibility to the default implementation.

```
public interface ICustomDialogService : IDialogService
{
   public void ShowOrphan(string name, IDialogParameters parameters, Action<IDialogResult> callback);
}
```

Create a type `CustomDialogService` derived from `ICustomDialogService` and copy the [original implementation](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/v7.2.0.1422/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Services/Dialogs/DialogService.cs) from GitHub. Adapt the original methods by passing down a parameter to the `ConfigureDialogWindowProperties` method to determine whether to set an `Owner` or not and act accordingly.

```
public class CustomDialogService : ICustomDialogService
{
   // ...other public members.

   public void ShowOrphan(string name, IDialogParameters parameters, Action<IDialogResult> callback)
   {
      // Appended a new parameter "isOrphan"
      ShowDialogInternal(name, parameters, callback, false, true);
   }

   // ...other private members.

   // Appended a new parameter "isOrphan"
   void ConfigureDialogWindowProperties(IDialogWindow window, FrameworkElement dialogContent, IDialogAware viewModel, bool isOrphan)
   {
      // ...other code.

      if (isOrphan)
         return;

      if (window.Owner == null)
         window.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
   }
}
```

Register the custom dialog service with your interface and the original interface so you can use both.

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton <CustomDialogService>();
containerRegistry.Register<IDialogService, CustomDialogService>();
containerRegistry.Register<ICustomDialogService, CustomDialogService>();
```

There might be other workarounds like creating a custom dialog host window that ignores the `Owner` property or other hacks, but I think that creating a custom dialog service is the cleanest approach here.

Comment: That's an excellent explanation, thanks! I have implemented as suggested and it works great.